# jqgrid set filter toolbar before titlebar

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, titlebar

I have a jqgrid with a filterToolbar correctly displaying:

```
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{autosearch:true});
```

I want it to display before the titlebar, how can I manage this?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want the filter boxes to appear above the column headers?

Comment: Yes I do, apologize for my english

Comment: No problem, just trying to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`toolbar`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option to place the toolbar at the top of the grid:

```
toolbar: [true, "top"]
```

This seems to achieve the effect you are looking for, as [demonstrated on the demo page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) under `New in version 3.1` | `Toolbars and userdata`.

Does that help?

Comment: it only adds a blank space over the titlebar.
My grid has:
titlebar
filtertoolbar
And I want to display:
filtertoolbar
titlebar